Coin Change: for loop analysis
I am trying to comprehend the problem which has different wording but I figured it is similar to coin change problem
Question:
Two friends are playing a game with a book numbered from 1 to 9. The game is played as follows:
On each turn, a player opens a page at random.

If the page number is even, the number is added to the player's score.
If the page number is odd, the player gets out and their turn ends.

Given a target score, determine the number of ways the player can achieve this score.
Example:
Input: 6
Output: 3

Explanation:
The player can achieve a score of 6 in the following ways:
(2, 2, 2)
(2, 4)
(6)

Solution I came up with, was dp tabulation (see below), to evaluate total ways for each score but that was the wrong answer. After swapping the internal & external for loop, I happen to get the correct solution.
I have tried understanding on paper by simulating various examples but not understanding intuitively why they both giving entirely different answers.
I would like to know in depth what was wrong in Code1 but was fixed in Code2 & why interchanging for loop would not work, and how can I improve myself for similar questions in future as I wasn't even getting the correct recursion relation at first.
int countWaysToAchieveScore(int target) {
    // Even numbers within the range 1 to 9
    vector<int> pages = {2, 4, 6, 8};

    // Create a dp array to store the number of ways to achieve each score
    vector<int> dp(target + 1, 0);
    dp[0] = 1; // There's one way to achieve a score of 0 (using no numbers)

    
    // Code1: WRONG
    // Input=8, Output=8
    /* 
    for (int i = 2; i <= target; i++) {
        for (int coin : pages) {
            if (i-coin >= 0) {
                dp[i] += dp[i-coin];
            }
        }
    }
    */
    

    // Code2: CORRECT
    // Input=8, Output=5
    for (int coin : pages) {
        for (int i = coin; i <= target; ++i) {
            dp[i] += dp[i - coin];
        }
    }

    // Return the number of ways to achieve the target score
    return dp[target];
}

Provide Input is such that:
target = 8;

The expected output = 5, same as Code2
Actual output from Code1 = 8
Some other examples I tried.
Example1:
Input = 10, Expected output(Code2) = 6, Actual Output(Code1) = 15

Example2:
Input = 12, Expected output(Code2) = 9, Actual Output(Code1) = 29


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems?r=Saves_AllUserSaves

With for (int i = 2; i <= target; i++) and dp[i] += ..., what happens with dp[1]? Will you ever add to it?

This is actually a good question, as the difference is indeed subtle. I've tried to explain in in my answer.

@lishant A better way to grasp (or replace) recursive function calls, is to use a loop, and std::stack<T> passed as reference in each iteration.

Huh, what's with the close votes? It's a valid algorithmic question. Now listing three examples of incorrect behavior instead of one. Nothing to do with a debugger though: the author specifically asked for explanation, not low-level variable values.

@Someprogrammerdude All odd values are of NO use and can be ZERO, as it does not contribute to even summation score

@Gassa Algorithm questions get closed all the time for strange reasons, especially when a specific language tag is added. It seems that many do not realize that asking for an algorithm is a valid question (not the case here, but happens often). I've voted to reopen.

@Gassa, yeah that's very authoritative and ambiguous way to close an algorithm question, I have provided sufficient examples that I tried but not able to see the reason why one works while other doesn't. Thanks for support.

Consider the first solution:
for (int i = 2; i <= target; i++)
    for (int coin : pages)
        if (i-coin >= 0)
            dp[i] += dp[i-coin];

This effectively counts the number of ways to get from 0 to target.
So, for example, "2 then 4" and "4 then 2" are considered as two different ways, and counted separately.

Consider the second solution:
for (int coin : pages)
    for (int i = coin; i <= target; ++i)
        dp[i] += dp[i - coin];

Here, note how in each path from 0 to target, the coins are sorted: first we consider coin = 2 and add it zero or more times, then we consider coin = 4 and add it zero or more times, and so on.
So, we count the way "2 then 4" but don't count the way "4 then 2".
In other words, from all possible orderings of coins on the path, we only consider one "canonical" ordering (coins sorted as in array "pages"), instead of treating each order separately.

Consider the example with target = 8.
The 8 ways to get from 0 to 8 are:

2 + 2 + 2 + 2
2 + 2 + 4
2 + 4 + 2 (same elements but different order)
4 + 2 + 2 (same elements but different order)
4 + 4
2 + 6
6 + 2 (same elements but different order)
8

The 5 multisets which occur above are the right answer.
The 3 other ways are in fact the same multisets in different orders.
The second solution takes 2 + 2 + 4 into account but discards 2 + 4 + 2 and 4 + 2 + 2, since these would require to add a 2 after a 4, which is prevented by loop order.
Similarly, 2 + 6 is counted by the right solution, but 6 + 2 isn't, since it would require to add a 2 after a 6.

so you mean, the 2nd solution is only working because the coins are sorted in ascending, otherwise it would have failed as well where as 1st solution is getting all the permutation, right?

@Lishant Even if they were sorted otherwise (say, 6, 2, 4, 8), it would have worked. Because every multiset will be counted exactly once (in this example, 2 + 2 + 4 but 6 + 2, because 6 is earlier than 2).

It's not that "the order is ascending". It's "we consider exactly one particular order". Whatever order we choose, it is unique.
